# Why when calculating subsets of an array, variable names seem to make a difference?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, backtracking

I'm trying to solve a programming interview problem where I have to generate the subsets of an array. Let's say the array is [1,2,3]. When I use:

```
def subsets(arr):
   def explore(arr, ans, temp, start, size):
      ans.append(temp[:])

      for i in range(start, size):
         #choose
         temp.append(arr[i])
         #explore
         explore(arr, ans, temp, start + 1, size)
         #undo
         temp.pop()
ans = []
size = len(arr)
explore(arr, ans, [], 0, size)
return ans
```

I get: [[], [1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3], [1, 3, 3], [2], [2, 2], [2, 2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3, 3], [3], [3, 2], [3, 2, 3], [3, 3], [3, 3, 3]]

However, when I use i instead of start, like so:

```
def subsets(arr):
def explore(arr, ans, temp, start, size):
    ans.append(temp[:])
    for i in range(start, size):
        #choose
        temp.append(arr[i])
        #explore
        explore(arr, ans, temp, i + 1, size)
        #undo
        temp.pop()
ans = []
size = len(arr)
explore(arr, ans, [], 0, size)
return ans
```

I get the right answer, [[], [1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3], [2], [2, 3], [3]].

What is going on here? I thought there would be no difference in the result since it is just a variable name difference.

Answer (score 1):

its not just any variable name difference, both variables viz. `i` and `start` hold different values. `i` iterates the list of integers which starts with `start` and ends with `size-1` in loop, whereas `start` is constant for all those loops. hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Would probably be a lot easier to use itertools...unless that is not allowed.

```
import itertools

stuff = [1, 2, 3]
for L in range(0, len(stuff)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(stuff, L):
        print(subset)
```

In terms of your question.  i is a value incremented in each iteration of your loop, start is the value of i on the first iteration.  Hence they are not interchangeable.